# ValueError: too many values to unpack (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, unpack

```
values = data.split("\x00")

username, passwordHash, startRoom, originUrl, bs64encode = values
if len(passwordHash)!= 0 and len(passwordHash)!= 64:
        passwordHash = ""
if passwordHash != "":
        passwordHash = hashlib.sha512(passwordHash).hexdigest()
username = username.replace("<", "")
if len(startRoom) > 200:
        startRoom = ""
startRoom = self.roomNameStrip(startRoom, "2").replace("<","").replace("&amp;#", "&amp;amp;#")
self.login(username, passwordHash, startRoom, originUrl)  


Error:
username, passwordHash, startRoom, originUrl, bs64encode = values
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding some text to state the question, instead of just posting code. It's likely to get your question upvoted more, and therefore more people will see it, and you'll be more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the output of

```
print len(values)
```

It has more than 5 values (which is the number of variables you are trying to "unpack" it to) which is causing your "too many values to unpack" error:

```
username, passwordHash, startRoom, originUrl, bs64encode = values
```

If you want to ignore the tail end elements of your list, you can do the following:

```
#assuming values has a length of 6
username, passwordHash, startRoom, originUrl, bs64encode, _ = values
```

or unpack only the first 5 elements (thanks to @JoelCornett)

```
#get the first 5 elements from the list
username, passwordHash, startRoom, originUrl, bs64encode = values[:5]
```

Comment: Might be better to do `arg1, arg2, arg3 = values[:3]` to ignore extra elements.

Comment: That's also another option - added to answer - thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing `values = data.split("\x00")` it's  producing more then 5 elements, probably not all values are separated by `\x00`.

Inspect the value of `values` with `print values` and check it's size with `len(values)`